# Who is awarded the goal?

Tags: rules, football

If a footballer plays a free kick and the footballer intention is to play the free kick direct to the goal post, but it touches the footballer team mate before entering the goal post, who is awarded the goal? Is it the free kick player or his team mate who the ball touches?

Answer (score 4):

Intention is irrelevant. The last attacker to play the ball will be considered the goalscorer, unless the goal is caused by the direct action of a defender and would probably not have scored otherwise.

Comment: This is generally correct. You won't be likely to find a source, because there are none. In most competitions, either the competition administrator, a committee or the referee makes the final decision, and how they do that is usually a matter for them.

Comment: [Here is some information](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2006/aug/23/theknowledge.sport) - potentially outdated now [2006] -  on the committee that decides in the Premier League.

Comment: [FIFA Magazine](http://www.fifa.com/news/y=1997/m=4/news=fifa-magazine-when-own-goal-not-own-goal-70226.html) also included an article about the topic in 1997 that may or may not be relevant anymore for their competitions.

Comment: @studro, these comments qualify to be a decent answer. Please keep in mind that we need to improve our [answer ratio](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports). It would be awesome if you could post a new answer with all these links.

Comment: If our answer ratio is a problem, our visitor numbers and question rate is a disaster. Having more answers for what is already here won't help a huge amount. @gdrt

Comment: @Nij, I believe, the extremely low **visitor number** is just a bug (we usually have a decent 6000-8000 here), it suddenly went down in [other communities](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551/chess) as well. **Question rate** is an eternal problem of Beta sites, there's nothing much we can do. But the answer ratio is something that we the answerers can improve and I think it's something that frequent users should keep in mind.

Comment: The issue for us is that sports questions often have a single reasonable and correct answer - who did this, what is the rule, when or where did this happen, what is the number - unlike the science or technology or personal sites where multiple perspectives and explanations can be provided in the same space largely without repetition. I think on balance, if a question has more than two different answers here, the correct ones are all the same, or the question is OT/TB/UC/POB.

Comment: This way or another, we need more answers on questions. If studro summarized his comments within a separate answer, we would have had 2 useful answers with the same conclusion but with different approaches: yours (based on personal experience) and studro's (based on references).

Comment: I didn't add an answer as I thought both of these sources were somewhat outdated. They were added as comments in case Nij wanted to add them to the answer to provide background on what football governing bodies thought about deciding the goalscorer 10 - 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Touching the ball alone doesn't make the player the goal scorer. Usually there are a few points that have to be considered...

- Would the ball go in without the player touching the ball?

If no the player who deflected the ball scored the goal. If yes it's up to the officials to decide (see below).

- How far did he deflect the ball and did he distract the keeper or defenders enough? Would the keeper have saved it without that player interfering?

If the ball went far enough off the original direction it's usually the deflecting player getting the credit for the goal. There's no written rule about how far the ball has to be deflected into another direction, so it's up to the officials to decide. But again, touching the ball alone doesn't make that player the scorer. Deflecting the ball by a few inches doesn't do that either (usually).

For example:

The kick would land right next to the post and it would be a goal either way....

- The ball rebounds off the leg of another player and the ball goes in at the other side of the goal. The deflecting player gets the credit (or an own goal if it was a defender).
- The ball is only lightly touched by that player and doesn't change it's direction. The player who took the free kick gets the credit for the goal.